# How laravel calls a method that is not in class and parrent

Tags: php, laravel, lumen, function-call, method-call

I wonder how laravel calls a method that is not present in class neither in the parent class.

For instance, I looked at the eloquent model class and never saw the **hydrate** method in it. the model class has no parent, yet when you call the hydrate method it fills attribute property of the model. After digging in the source I found the hydrate class in **Builder.php** class. So how laravel manage to call that method in another class? Is it some kind of method injection?

Answer (score 5):

PHP offers a magic method named `__call`. If a method that doesn't exist in a class is invoked, the `__call` method is triggered. Laravel leverages this mechanism to simulate invoking methods from another class as if they were methods of the current class, which can be likened to inheritance but is distinct in its implementation. It's a nuanced approach that requires a clear understanding of method implementation in classes.

In previous Laravel versions, this was used in the Eloquent abstract class:

```php
public function __call($method, $parameters)
{
    if (in_array($method, ['increment', 'decrement'])) {
        return $this->$method(...$parameters);
    }

    return $this->newQuery()->$method(...$parameters);
}
```

In the code above, if you invoke the `hydrate` method, and it isn't found in the current class, Laravel resorts to the query builder class and calls the method there.

From Laravel version 5.5 onwards, this strategy was revamped. A trait named `Illuminate\Support\Traits\ForwardsCalls` was introduced. This trait includes the `forwardCallTo()` method:

```php
protected function forwardCallTo($object, $method, $parameters)
{
    try {
        return $object->{$method}(...$parameters);
    } catch (Error | BadMethodCallException $e) {
        $pattern = '~^Call to undefined method (?P<class>[^:]+)::(?P<method>[^\(]+)\(\)$~';
        if (!preg_match($pattern, $e->getMessage(), $matches)) {
            throw $e;
        }
        if ($matches['class'] != get_class($object) || $matches['method'] != $method) {
            throw $e;
        }
        static::throwBadMethodCallException($method);
    }
}
```

The `forwardCallTo()` method essentially delegates a method call from one class to another. Consequently, the `__call` method was adapted to:

```php
public function __call($method, $parameters)
{
    if (in_array($method, ['increment', 'decrement'])) {
        return $this->$method(...$parameters);
    }
    return $this->forwardCallTo($this->newQuery(), $method, $parameters);
}
```

Here's a key benefit of this architectural choice: Suppose you're working with a model, like the `User` model, which extends from `Eloquent\Model`. While you might want to allow developers to override certain methods without turning them private, this structure gives a level of control over what can be overridden.

For illustration, while the `User` model can override any protected or public method in `Eloquent\Model`, a developer can only really access and override the `hydrate()` method and not, for example, the `getModels()` method due to the following code in the builder class:

```php
public function getModels($columns = ['*'])
{
    return $this->model->hydrate(
        $this->query->get($columns)->all()
    )->all();
}
```

Though the `hydrate()` method is primarily located in `Builder.php` and not `Model.php`, because of the magic of `__call`, it's accessible through the `Model` class.

To clarify, this doesn't mean you can't override the `getModels()` method in the `User` model. You can, and if you invoke it directly through a `User` model instance, it will respect your override. However, during Eloquent's data fetching process, it won't be overridden in the builder class since it's not being routed through the model.

In simpler terms, you can override builder methods in a model only if they are invoked via the model class.

Comment: Very clean and complete explanation. Thanks a lot. But I didn't understand the last line " If you get to override the getModels() in the User model and the make a new instance of User model and try to call getModels() it definitely class overridden method."

Comment: @SelimKaraca sry bad english. :D I fix the last part you can check it now. don't forget to upvote and make it as best answer